# CSS - How to centre a link button

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an Events app using Rails and I'm currently styling my index page. I don't have a nav/header bar, rather I have my site logo in the top right hand corner with my links buttons directly underneath. 
When a user first logs on they see the logo with a link to 'Create An Event' under the logo. When clicked it takes them to a sign-in page. When they're signed in they have 2 links under the logo, one for 'Create Event' and one for 'Profile'. The 2 links when signed in are side-by-side and sit neatly under the logo. However, when not signed in the 'Create an Event' link (id = eventlink) sits under the logo but to the left. I want this link to sit directly centred under the logo. I've tried lots of different variations but it simply won't shift. How do I solve this?

Here's the code -

index.html.erb

```
<div id="logosignin" class="col-md-4">

                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <%= image_tag('MamaKnowsLogo.jpg') %>
                        <li><%= link_to 'Create Event', new_event_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to 'Profile', user_path(current_user) %></li>

                    <% else %>
                        <%= image_tag('MamaKnowsLogo.jpg') %>
                        <li id="eventlink"><%= link_to 'Create An Event', new_user_session_path %></li>
                    <% end %>
            </div>
```

events.css.scss -

```
 #logosignin img {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

#logosignin {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 20px;
    float: right;




}

#logosignin a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FF69B4;


 }



#eventnav {
    height: 75px;
}

#logosignin li {
    bottom: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;

   }

#eventshow {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#eventlink {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    left: 20px;

}
```

Comment: Try for `display: table` instead of `text-align:center` in the `#eventlink`

Comment: No. Tried that, it doesn't work either. I think some of my other CSS rules are overriding what I'm trying to do with this link but can't figure out what.

Comment: I see that you are using bootstrap. What don't you take the logo off from if condition and place logo in one div class row-fluid and menu in another div class row-fluid???

Comment: I take your point on the logo, how would that solve this issue? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added text-center class to align the menu items to center. Added display:block to menu  item. Check static code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n46azhrj/2/).

```css
 #logosignin img {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#logosignin {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 20px;
    float: right;
}
#logosignin a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
 }
#eventnav {
    height: 75px;
}
#logosignin li {
    bottom: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
#eventshow {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#eventlink {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    left: 20px;
}
.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="logosignin" class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row-fluid text-center">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid text-center">
      <li id="eventlink"><a href="#">Create event</a></li>
      <li id="eventlink"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: definitely it will use if condition on the last row-fluid.